# How do I save a wordcloud as a .png using the wordcloud2 package in r?

Tags: r

I've created a wordcloud using the 'wordcloud2' package in r and I want to save the output as a .png (or really any image file). I know that I can just save the initial output as a .png and use that, but the data that the wordcloud uses changes every time the document is knit (the data is tweets gathered using the rtweet::search_tweet function), and I want the wordcloud to be updated with the same info.

I've tried using the webshot & htmlwidget packages to save the wordcloud as .png, but I always get a blank image. I've even changed the delay to 120 seconds to make sure that I gave the wordcloud enough time to load properly. The original wordcloud output is ~1.6 MB if the size might be a problem.

Here's my code:

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(webshot)
library(htmlwidgets)

Bcloud <-
  wordcloud2(wordFreq,
           size = 1,
           figPath = "images/#Bv2.png",
           color = colorVec)

Bcloud
# 
saveWidget(Bcloud, "tmp.html", selfcontained = F)
webshot("tmp.html", "wordcloud.png", delay = 120, vwidth = 2000, vheight = 2000)
```

UPDATE: I removed `figPath = "images/#Bv2.png"` and changed the shape to one of the standard options (star, triangle, diamond, etc.) and now the wordcloud saves as a .png using `saveWidget()` and `webshot()`. I guess the issue is with the mask. The image I'm using for the mask is 13.1 KB.

Comment: have you tried built in `png` function? After you execute the plotting command, you can try `png(filename='your_filename.png')` this should save the plot in your current working directory.

Comment: Just tried the built in `png` function, but it just produced a blank image.

Comment: `png` does not work because it is a graphics device. `wordcloud2` generates an html page that loads in the default browser.